# Originate call without ringing local extension

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am using asterisk AMI to originate call.I am calling to a folder which contains phone number of customers. In current scenario, i am using xlite, from where call is originating but xlite is disconnecting every time hangup current call and we are clicking on xlite green button for sending call to next customer phone number.
What my requirement is, When i click on that folder, call should originate once and once the current call is disconnected from customer end, next call should start (not originate) for next customer number. Is there anyway to do so?

In short, Asterisk AMI Originate: Without Extension Local Ringing is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage multiple dials using dialplan using Local/ channel

You can call to queue as agent(there is possible agent which always on phone) and create new calls to queue.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please elaborate it?